# What is the difference between Jest Mock functions and Sinon spies

Tags: javascript, sinon, jestjs

I am mocking a function with Jest and the documentation says they are really 'spies'. I have also seen the use of spies in SinonJS but I could find no clear difference between the two. If they are serving the same purpose, is there any reason to choose one over the other?

[Jest Mock Functions](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockimplementationfn)

[SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The main behaviour of both is the same, they are functions that can remember their calls. So for both you can figure out how often they were called and with which arguments. Sinon has a much wider API for what you can test on spies, and it has an API to replace functions in objects with spies.

Comment: more importantly sinon API is very easy and more natural comparing to Jest's implementation

Comment: sinon API being easy and natural is something personal. I always found very difficult to work with sinon and whenever I can I switch to another library or write my own wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a caveat when using Sinon Vs Jest.
In my case I wanted to mock a whole module and check if this was being called from the main function I was testing:

```
parent func(){  // The func my test was about
   childFunc() // The call I tried to mock and check if it was called.
...
```

, I tried using `Sinon.spy(module, 'default')` But kept throwing errors saying couldn't find 'default'.
Seems stub, spy, and mock are all good when you want to mock results for function or you have functional properties. In my case switching to jest was super simple and achieved what I needed by just using

jest.mock('./module')